# Using DECLARE throws invalid SQL statement

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc to connect to a .mdb file and do somethings.

```
sql = ("""\
  DECLARE @i int  = 1;
  ...somevalid sql...
""")
cursor.execute(sql)
```

The above gives me the error `"Invalid SQL Statement; expected 'Delete',....`.

`@i` is not used anywhere in the sql, and the sql below will run without the declare statement. I have seen in multiple places other people DO do this like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51509024/5471957) so it is supposed to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connecting to an Access database (.mdb) so you need to use the Microsoft Access dialect of SQL. `DECLARE` is a T-SQL statement (the Microsoft SQL Server dialect of SQL) that is not valid for Access SQL.

Note also that Access SQL only supports the execution of one SQL statement at a time.

Comment: Oh I see, I haven't really used access before. so I guess something like this is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13629639/5471957

Comment: Not in that form (anonymous code block). Try asking a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) describing what you actually want to accomplish.